# Weak derivative and approximation

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ be absolutely continuous. Is it true that if $f_n$ is a sequence of Lipschitz functions s.t. $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^2$ and $ f_n' \rightarrow g $ in $L^2$ then $ \|g\|_{L^2} \geq \|f'\|_{L^2}$?

Comment: In fact, $g = f'$ (as elements of $L^2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true in even weaker hypothesis, i.e. only weak convergence. In fact, taking $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$, we have
$$
\begin{matrix}
\int f'_n \phi & = & - \int f_n \phi'\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
\int g \phi & & -\int f \phi' &= \int f' \phi
\end{matrix}
$$
therefore $f'=g$ a.e..